# WordPress: populate text editor with another post in <blockquote>

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, add-filter

My goal is relatively simple, and I have the impression I can achieve what I want with either a custom post type, a filter hook, or both: I want to put "quote" buttons near each post that create a new post with the editor pre-populated with the quoted post enclosed in  tags. I know I can create a function that changes the default_content filter, but I think I should pass in a custom post type (my theme can generate a link that provides the post_ID of the post to be quoted) instead? I've looked at the add_filter() function, not sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: I found elsewhere that I should use something similar to this (sorry for the crappy formatting):  `function quote_a_post( $the_quoted_post, $post_id_derp ) {  
 $the_post_to_quote = get_post( $post_id_derp);  
 $the_quoted_post = "<blockquote>" + $the_post_to_quote->post_content + "</blockquote>";  
 return $the_quoted_post;  
}   
add_filter( 'quoted_post', 'quote_a_post' );`

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Pretty sure I should add a filter for "default_content", but within this filter function I want to retrieve a certain post. Session variables aren't an option as there are several posts that could be quoted; when does a filter trigger?

Answer (score 0):

After research I found that a filter function added with add_filter fires within the context of post-new.php and I can access variables passed in via the URL using $_GET[] to conditionally format the text I populate the editor with.